# Como salvar os valores de uma String em uma variável Double?

Tags: java, tipagem, atributos

Tenho uma String com o valor x dentro dela

(String valor = "x")

Preciso passar esse valor para uma Variável Double, como faço para passar o valor de x da String para a variável? Sendo que se eu converter de String para Double o valor da variável Double fica nulo.

saldo = Double.parseDouble(valor);  <--- Após a conversão o valor fica nulo

Existe uma maneira para coletar esse valor e salvar em uma variável Double?

Comment: Como assim fica nulo? Aqui ocorreu normal, veja: https://ideone.com/BZ0T0z

Comment: Você quer transformar um valor 'x' em String, por exemplo '1.2', para double ou quer transformar realmente o 'x' para double?

Comment: Digamos que o valor de X seja:

String x = 700;

Como faço para passar esse valor (700) para uma variável Double?

Comment: O que tem na sua variável valor antes de você para ela para o Double.parseDouble?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166386/parsing-string-to-double-java

Comment: Alexandre, veja o exemplo do link que mandei, não problema algum. Esse método funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 3):

O método parseDouble é o mais usado para fazer esse tipo de conversão.

```
public class ConvertStringToDouble {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String aString = "700";
    double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(aString);

    System.out.println(aDouble);
  }
}
```

> Você pode também fazer o `CAST` para converter para o seu tipo.

```
double aDouble = (Double)aString;
```

> Usar o Double.valueOf

O método estático Double.valueOf () irá retornar um objeto Double mantendo o valor da seqüência especificada .

Sintaxe

```
String numberAsString = "153.25";
double number = Double.valueOf(numberAsString);
System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
```

> Converter usando new Double(String).doubleValue()

```
String numberAsString = "153.25";
Double doubleObject = new Double(numberAsString);
double number = doubleObject.doubleValue();
```

Podemos encurtar para:

```
String numberAsString = "153.25";
double number = new Double(numberAsString).doubleValue();
```

Ou;

```
double number = new Double("153.25").doubleValue();
```

> Converte usando DecimalFormat

O java.text.DecimalFormat classe é uma classe que pode ser usado para converter um número para a sua representação de String . Ele também pode ser usado no sentido inverso - ele pode analisar um String em sua representação numérica.
Exemplo

```
String numberAsString = "153.25";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
try {
   double number = decimalFormat.parse(numberAsString).doubleValue();
   System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
} catch (ParseException e) {
   System.out.println(numberAsString + " is not a valid number.");
}
```

Obs:  se sua string contive **,** no lugar do **.** , o ideal e fazer um  *replace* antes de tenta converte.

```
String number = "123,321";
double value = Double.parseDouble(number.replace(",",".") );
```

[Veja funcionado aqui.](http://goo.gl/1yJFL5)